# How can I escape curly braces in a Docxgen field?

Tags: javascript

I have a document docx with some tags, for example:

```
{-w:p questionario}
    {nominativo} (...)
{/questionariodioc}
```

Sometimes into "nominativo" field can be inserted a text between curly braces, but when setData is invoked, I receive the following error:
You can't enter { or } inside the content of the variable Tag: nominativo, Value: {Mario Rossi}.

How can I escape curly braces into fields?

I tried to insert a backslash before and after the value, but I receive the same error